# SQL - How do I use a subquery instead of a Temp Table to make this query run?

Tags: sql, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have this SQL query that I running thorough the Power BI/Snowflake connector:

```
create temporary table DS_TEMP (INC text, Ass_Group text, SEQ_NO int);

INSERT INTO DS_TEMP
SELECT INCIDENT_HISTORY_PUBLIC.INCIDENT_NUMBER, Assigned_Group, 
Assigned_Group_SEQ_NO 
from INCIDENT_HISTORY_PUBLIC 
where ASSIGNED_GROUP LIKE ' DS$_%' ESCAPE '$';

SELECT DISTINCT INCIDENT_HISTORY_PUBLIC.INCIDENT_NUMBER, ASSIGNED_GROUP, 
ASSIGNED_GROUP_SEQ_NO, History_Start_Date
from INCIDENT_HISTORY_PUBLIC, DS_TEMP
where INCIDENT_HISTORY_PUBLIC.INCIDENT_NUMBER = DS_TEMP.INC 
AND INCIDENT_HISTORY_PUBLIC.ASSIGNED_GROUP NOT LIKE '%Help_Desk%' 
AND ASSIGNED_GROUP_SEQ_NO < DS_TEMP.SEQ_NO
ORDER BY INCIDENT_HISTORY_PUBLIC.INCIDENT_NUMBER, ASSIGNED_GROUP_SEQ_NO;
```

Instead of creating a temp table, is there a way I just use a sub-query to achieve the same results?

I've tried to use an inner join along with max() but am having no luck.

Comment: Hi - why does a simple inner join not work? Why would you need to use max() in your join - there’s nothing in your existing SQL that has any “max” logic?

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using CTEs?

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/queries-cte.html

I'm writing this one without any testing:

```
with DS_TEMP as (
SELECT INCIDENT_HISTORY_PUBLIC.INCIDENT_NUMBER, Assigned_Group, 
Assigned_Group_SEQ_NO 
from INCIDENT_HISTORY_PUBLIC 
where ASSIGNED_GROUP LIKE ' DS$_%' ESCAPE '$'
)
SELECT DISTINCT INCIDENT_HISTORY_PUBLIC.INCIDENT_NUMBER, ASSIGNED_GROUP, 
ASSIGNED_GROUP_SEQ_NO, History_Start_Date
from INCIDENT_HISTORY_PUBLIC, DS_TEMP
where INCIDENT_HISTORY_PUBLIC.INCIDENT_NUMBER = DS_TEMP.INC 
AND INCIDENT_HISTORY_PUBLIC.ASSIGNED_GROUP NOT LIKE '%Help_Desk%' 
AND ASSIGNED_GROUP_SEQ_NO < DS_TEMP.SEQ_NO
ORDER BY INCIDENT_HISTORY_PUBLIC.INCIDENT_NUMBER, ASSIGNED_GROUP_SEQ_NO;
```